# Counting number of factors that occur in a data frame then only deleting that row if the number of factors is less than or equal to x

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where the `$type` variable is factor.

`df <- data.frame(type=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd'), state=c('Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington'))`

Goal: `a` and `b` appear 3 or more times, but `c` and `d` only appears twice and once. I want to delete the rows where df$type has `c` and `d` so new df should look like this:

`df <- data.frame(type=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a'),
state=c('Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington','Washington'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `table()` and `%in%`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  type = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "c", "a", "d"),
  state = rep("Washington", 9)
)

to_keep <- names(table(df$type))[table(df$type) >= 3]
df <- df[df$type %in% to_keep, ]

df

#>  type      state
#> 1    a Washington
#> 2    a Washington
#> 3    b Washington
#> 5    b Washington
#> 6    b Washington
#> 8    a Washington
```

Answer (score 4):

And using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  filter(n()>2)
```